# Python flask. Как проверить наличие email в базе данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

При регистрации пользователя нужно проверить email на уникальность,
что бы не регистрировать пользователей с одинаковыми email.
Подключение к базе через MySql и SQLAlchemy.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root@localhost/test_db'
```

Добавление записей в таблицу при регистрации происходит через класс Users:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    psw = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
```

Тут сама регистрация:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def user_register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(request.form['name']) > 3 and len(request.form['email']) > 3:
            try:
                hash = generate_password_hash(request.form['psw'])
                u = Users(name=request.form['name'],email=request.form['email'], psw=hash)
                db.session.add(u)
                db.session.flush()            

                flash('Account was created', category='success')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))

            except:
                db.session.rollback()
                flash('DB ERROR! Note did not add', category='error')

        else:
            flash('Wrong fields', category='error')

    return render_template('register.html')
```

В данном виде, если при регистрации указать email, который уже есть в базе, то происходит исключение, так как при создании БД полю email задается значение unicue. 
Но это исключение происходит если не удалось создать запись в БД.
При этом, причины по которым не получилось создать запись могут быть разными.
Как проверить, существует ли уже в БД пользователь с email, который указывается при регистрации с целью дальнейшей обработки этого условия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
email = request.form['email']

# если поиск по email в таблице ничего не возвращает
if not Users.query.filter(Users.email == email):
    # добавление пользователя
    # ...
```

Comment: Попробовал. С такой проверкой регистрация не проходит, так как любой email определяется, как уже существующий.

Comment: if not Users.query.filter(Users.email == request.form['email']).all(): далее добавление. В таком виде работает.